# Create/Insert Json in Postgres with requests and psycopg2

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Just started a project with `PostgreSQL`. I would like to make the leap from Excel to a database and I am stuck on create and insert. Once I run this I will have to switch it to Update I believe so I don't continue to write over the current data. I know my connection is working but i get the following error.

My Error is: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='NHL', user='postgres', password='postgres', host='localhost', port='5432')

req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=skatersummary&sort=[{%22property%22:%22playerName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22},{%22property%22:%22goals%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22},{%22property%22:%22assists%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22}]&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3E=20172018%20and%20seasonId%3C=20172018') 
data = req.json()['data']

my_data = []
for item in data:
    season = item['seasonId']
    player = item['playerName']
    first_name = item['playerFirstName']
    last_Name = item['playerLastName']
    playerId = item['playerId']
    height = item['playerHeight']
    pos = item['playerPositionCode']
    handed = item['playerShootsCatches']
    city = item['playerBirthCity']
    country = item['playerBirthCountry']   
    state = item['playerBirthStateProvince']
    dob = item['playerBirthDate']
    draft_year = item['playerDraftYear']
    draft_round = item['playerDraftRoundNo']
    draft_overall = item['playerDraftOverallPickNo']
    my_data.append([playerId, player, first_name, last_Name, height, pos, handed, city, country, state, dob, draft_year, draft_round, draft_overall, season])

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t_skaters (data json);")
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t_skaters VALUES (%s)", (my_data,))
```

Sample of `data:`

```
[[8468493, 'Ron Hainsey', 'Ron', 'Hainsey', 75, 'D', 'L', 'Bolton', 'USA', 'CT', '1981-03-24', 2000, 1, 13, 20172018], [8471339, 'Ryan Callahan', 'Ryan', 'Callahan', 70, 'R', 'R', 'Rochester', 'USA', 'NY', '1985-03-21', 2004, 4, 127, 20172018]]
```

Comment: I suppose you should `my_data.append(playerId, player, first_name, last_Name, height, pos, handed, city, country, state, dob, draft_year, draft_round, draft_overall, season)` instead  -you dont need 2d array here

Comment: I’m not sure I follow Vao, I have data.append

Comment: my point was: don't append array of array - remove square brackets in `my_data.append(` fn()

Comment: Removed the square brackets and now I get `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (15 given)`

Comment: That can't be a sample of `data` - you are indexing items in `data` by string, which indicates that `data` should be a `list` of `dict`. I think there are multiple problems with your query syntax - try using `mogrify()` to make sure that you're getting the statement you expect. It may just be easier for you to call `execute()` in a loop as per the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) `executemany()` is not faster.

Comment: If I just do a print(my_data) that’s how it looks. There very well could be problems, new to programming/python and very new to databases in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want to create a table with one column named `"data"`. The type of this column is JSON. (I would recommend creating one column per field, but it's up to you.)

In this case the variable `data` (that is read from the request) is a `list` of `dict`s. As I mentioned in my comment, you can loop over `data` and do the inserts one at a time as `executemany()` is not faster than multiple calls to `execute()`.

What I did was the following:

1. Create a list of fields that you care about.
2. Loop over the elements of `data`
3. For each `item` in `data`, extract the fields into `my_data`
4. Call `execute()` and pass in `json.dumps(my_data)` (Converts `my_data` from a `dict` into a JSON-string)

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='NHL', user='postgres', password='postgres', host='localhost', port='5432')

req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=skatersummary&sort=[{%22property%22:%22playerName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22},{%22property%22:%22goals%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22},{%22property%22:%22assists%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22}]&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3E=20172018%20and%20seasonId%3C=20172018') 

# data here is a list of dicts
data = req.json()['data']

cur = conn.cursor()
# create a table with one column of type JSON
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t_skaters (data json);")

fields = [
    'seasonId',
    'playerName',
    'playerFirstName',
    'playerLastName',
    'playerId',
    'playerHeight',
    'playerPositionCode',
    'playerShootsCatches',
    'playerBirthCity',
    'playerBirthCountry',
    'playerBirthStateProvince',
    'playerBirthDate',
    'playerDraftYear',
    'playerDraftRoundNo',
    'playerDraftOverallPickNo'
]

for item in data:
    my_data = {field: item[field] for field in fields}
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO t_skaters VALUES (%s)", (json.dumps(my_data),))


# commit changes
conn.commit()
# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

I am not 100% sure if all of the postgres syntax is correct here (I don't have access to a PG database to test), but I believe that this logic should work for what you are trying to do.

**Update For Separate Columns**

You can modify your create statement to handle multiple columns, but it would require knowing the data type of each column. Here's some psuedocode you can follow:

```
# same boilerplate code from above
cur = conn.cursor()
# create a table with one column per field
cur.execute(
"""CREATE TABLE t_skaters (seasonId INTEGER, playerName VARCHAR, ...);"""
)

fields = [
    'seasonId',
    'playerName',
    'playerFirstName',
    'playerLastName',
    'playerId',
    'playerHeight',
    'playerPositionCode',
    'playerShootsCatches',
    'playerBirthCity',
    'playerBirthCountry',
    'playerBirthStateProvince',
    'playerBirthDate',
    'playerDraftYear',
    'playerDraftRoundNo',
    'playerDraftOverallPickNo'
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    # need a placeholder (%s) for each variable 
    # refer to postgres docs on INSERT statement on how to specify order
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO t_skaters VALUES (%s, %s, ...)", tuple(my_data))


# commit changes
conn.commit()
# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

Replace the `...` with the appropriate values for your data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right, i would like it to be multiple fields. Not just 1. However, I tried running what you have provided and I do not get an error but I do not get a table either. How would i write the above example in a manner in which it stores the fields provided in seperate columns?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't do anything because we didn't call `commit()`. I'll edit the post. As for separate columns, you have to explicitly define them in your create statement and modify the insert statement accordingly.

Comment: I will try that thank you! is the %s, %s in the insert stand for seasonId and playerName for the create table above? so i remove the ... and add the name and data type, then below i add the %s for each placeholder for each variable. very cool, thank you for the lesson! I love it when the answer is explained as well!

Comment: Yes, columns are comma separated but you also have to specify the datatype. The placeholders are one for each column, so yes in my example the two `%s` instances correspond to `seasonId` and `playerName`. Google "postgres create table" and they will show you some examples. If this works, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I tried with just 1 entry and I got this error. `cur.execute("INSERT INTO t_skaters VALUES (%s)", tuple(my_data))`
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: You need one `%s` for each element in your tuple.

Comment: The problem was i left `fields = [` with all of the entrys. and just tried for 2 of them. After clearing field down to only the ones i want it worked. Thanks! I can just switch it to update now and remove the create table going forward correct?

Comment: You only need to create the table once. I believe postgres supports functionality to create the table if it doesn't exist. Google `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` for postgres.